# Convert string to custom type using Convert

Tags: c#, class, types

I'm reading a string-value from an XML-file, which I need to convert to a certain (custom) type.

In my case I have an InputPatch class that specifies the wanted type[ValueType], so I need to convert the string to `inputPatch.ValueType`.

I want to do :

```
inputPatch.DefaultValue = Convert.ChangeType(
    defaultValueAttribute.Value, inputPatch.ValueType,
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But for my `BitmapFilename` class (which does have a string constructor) the result is

> Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'ProjectX.Node.BitmapFilename'.

So, how can I get Convert to convert a string to my own BitmapFilename class ?

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't use `Convert` for this; instead, you can use:

```
TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(inputPatch.ValueType);
object value = converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(defaultValueAttribute.Value);
```

this does require you to subclass `TypeConverter`, and mark the converter for your type. However, it will work for all the standard types, and is extensible.

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(BitmapFilenameConverter))]
public class BitmapFilename {...}

class BitmapFilenameConverter : TypeConverter {
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
        CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        string s = value as string;
        if(s != null) {
              /***** YOUR CODE HERE ******/
        } else {
            return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
        }
    }
}
```

and of course, write the converter code!

Answer (score 0):

Because you're going to actually support any custom type, you have to come up with your own solution: implement your custom convertion logic. That could be easily done using Reflection.

Regards,
Artak

Comment: I have a string. I have a type which can be constructed with a string-parameter. Surely there must be a way to get to a generic string-to-whatever-type conversion without implementing a custom converter ?

Comment: There should be a custom logic ! Implement it in eidther Extension method, or any other method, but the logic you have to write yourself. .Net smart enough, but no so much to understand what somebody has written in the string and how that should be treated.

Answer (score -1):

Have your class implement [IConvertible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx)

**EDITED**: To convert FROM other types, try [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Comment: It seems that IConvertible is used to convert a value TO something.
I dont want to convert my BitmapFilename class to something, I want to Convert a string TO a BitmapFilename using System.Convert..
Or am I missing something in IConvertible that would help me with this ?

Comment: Try extension methods - as I mentioned in my edit above. However, whether or not this is a good idea from an architectural aspect is another issue altogether.

Comment: My apologies, I'm not sure I understand how I should use extension methods to have System.Convert conver a string to my custom type ?
Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: My application uses plugins, so the custom types aren't known at compiletime. I have no control over the types that can be converted to, but I can impose a structure that would make this work - but first I have to find one :)

Comment: The way I'd go about this is by constructing the requested type at runtime by using `System.Activator` class, then use reflection to populate fields and properties. I'm assuming the file's format is outside of your control - if not, you can use XmlSerializer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) to do the serialization for you.